# Infinispan java.lang.SecurityException: ISPN006017: Unauthorized 'PUT' operation

Tags: infinispan, redhat-datagrid

I am trying to put a value in Infinispan cache using Hotrod nodeJS client. The code runs fine if the server is installed locally. However, when I run the same code with Infinispan server hosted on docker container I get the following error

**java.lang.SecurityException: ISPN006017: Unauthorized 'PUT' operation**

```js
 try {
    client = await infinispan.client({
      port: 11222,
      host: '127.0.0.1'
    }, {
      cacheName: 'testcache'
    });
    console.log(`Connected to cache`);

    await client.put('test', 'hello 1');

    await client.disconnect();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    await client.disconnect();
  }
```

I have tried setting CORS Allow all option on the server as well

Answer (score 0):

Need to provide custom config.yaml to docker with following configurations
endpoints:
  hotrod:
    auth: false
    enabled: false
    qop: auth
    serverName: infinispan

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the nodejs client doesn't support authentication yet. The issue to implement this is https://issues.redhat.com/projects/HRJS/issues/HRJS-36